# No match found for operator= (find value in vector<string>)

Tags: c++, vector, find

I'm clearly missing something here, but what?

Definition (`...` denotes valid code, not actual three points):

```
class CrmxFile {
private:
    const std::vector<std::string> validValues;
    int value;

public:
    void setValue(std::string _value);

...
}

std::vector<std::string> CrmxFile = {...};
```

In the code I have this:

```
void Crmx::SetValue(std::string _value) {
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator idx;
    if((idx = std::find(validValues.begin(), validValues.end(), _value)) == validValues.end()) {
        value = 0;
    }
    else {
        value = idx - validValues.begin();
    }
}
```

I compile this with `gcc -c -std=c++0x` and I get this error:

```
CrmxFile.cpp: In member function ‘void CrmxFile::SetValue(std::string)’:
CrmxFile.cpp:24:64: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘idx = std::find [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >, _Tp = std::basic_string<char>](Id3V1::validValues.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::const_pointer = const std::basic_string<char>*](), Id3V1::validValues.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::const_pointer = const std::basic_string<char>*](), (*(const std::basic_string<char>*)(& _value)))’
CrmxFile.cpp:24:64: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:702:11: note: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::operator=(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:702:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >’ to ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:702:11: note: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::operator=(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:702:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >’ to ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >&&’
```

What am I missing?  Or, alternatively, is there a better way of finding the index of a given value in a vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`idx` has to be a `const_iterator` since  `validValues` is a `const vector<...>`.

```
std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator idx;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `validValues` is `const`, `begin()`, `end()`, and therefore this instantiation of `std::find`, all return `std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator`, not `std::vector<std::string>::iterator`.  For const-safety, a `const_iterator` cannot convert to an `iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

`validValues` is defined as `const std::vector<std::string>`. Therefore `begin()` and `end()` will return `const_iterator`, but you are trying to assign the result to a `iterator`. Converting a `const_iterator` to an `iterator` would break const correctness (since you could then go on and change the underlying object) and is therefore not allowed.

Change the definition of `idx`  to be `std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

"What am I missing?"

Is yours first validValues invalid?

I suggest:

```
void Crmx::SetValue(std::string _value) {

        value = std::find(validValues.begin(), validValues.end(), _value) - validValues.begin();

}
```

and use the validValues.size as invalid value, not 0

Comment: All values are valid.  I need to use 0, as 0 is a valid value.  The requirement is to default to 0 if input is not one of valid ones.  @ipc has the right answer - it worked for me.